# Iterate in two lists with different objects

Tags: c#

I am trying to iterate in two list with different objects.I am adding the records to a third list if they complete the following conditions when I compare `listTest1` and `listTest2`

- If the `abbrv` and the `date` is the same I am adding the object from `listTest2` to `listTest3`
- If the `abbrv` is the same but the `date` is different I am adding the object from `listTest2` to `listTest3` and I am switching the completed property to `true`. In addition, I am adding the record from `listTest1` to `listTest3`.
- If the `abbrv` from `listTest1` doesn't exist in `listTest2` I am adding the record from `listTest1` to `listTest3`.

I know that it sounds quite confusing that is why I will show you what I am getting and what I am expecting.

I am getting:

[image: My image]

I need to get all these records but the duplicate(Test2).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test1 test1 = new Test1() { abbrv = "Test1", date = new DateTime(2017, 11, 12), completed = false };
    Test1 test2 = new Test1() { abbrv = "Test2", date = new DateTime(2017, 12, 17), completed = false };
    Test1 test5 = new Test1() { abbrv = "Test5", date = new DateTime(2017, 12, 12), completed = false };
    Test2 test3 = new Test2() { abbrv = "Test1", date = new DateTime(2017, 11, 12), completed = false, abbrevName = "AbbrvName1" };
    Test2 test4 = new Test2() { abbrv = "Test2", date = new DateTime(2017, 12, 12), completed = false, abbrevName = "AbbrvName2" };
    List<Test1> listTest1 = new List<Test1>();
    List<Test2> listTest2 = new List<Test2>();
    List<Test2> listTest3 = new List<Test2>();
    listTest1.Add(test1);
    listTest1.Add(test2);
    listTest1.Add(test5);
    listTest2.Add(test3);
    listTest2.Add(test4);
    for (int i = 0; i < listTest1.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < listTest2.Count; a++)
        {
            if (listTest1[i].abbrv == listTest2[a].abbrv && listTest1[i].date == listTest2[a].date)
            {
                if (!listTest3.Any(x => x.abbrv == listTest1[i].abbrv))
                {
                    listTest3.Add(listTest2[a]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (listTest1[i].abbrv == listTest2[a].abbrv)
                {
                    if (!listTest3.Any(x => x.abbrv == listTest1[i].abbrv && x.date != listTest1[i].date))
                    {
                        listTest3.Add(new Test.Test2() { abbrv = listTest2[a].abbrv, date = listTest2[a].date, completed = true, abbrevName = listTest2[a].abbrevName });
                        listTest3.Add(new Test.Test2() { abbrv = listTest1[i].abbrv, date = listTest1[i].date, completed = listTest1[i].completed, abbrevName = string.Empty });
                    }

                }
                else if (listTest1[i].abbrv != listTest2[a].abbrv)
                {
                    if(!listTest3.Any(x => x.abbrv == listTest1[i].abbrv))
                    {
                        listTest3.Add(new Test.Test2() { abbrv = listTest1[i].abbrv, date = listTest1[i].date, completed = listTest1[i].completed, abbrevName = string.Empty });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Test1
{
    public string abbrv { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public bool completed { get; set; }
}
public class Test2
{
    public string abbrv { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public bool completed { get; set; }
    public string abbrevName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You implemented the first two conditions correctly, but the third condition cannot be implemented in the innermost loop: you cannot tell if `abbrv` from `listTest1` exists in `listTest2` until your inner loop is over.

Add a `bool` variable `abbrvFound` indicating that an `abbrv` is found. Set it to `false` before entering the nested loop; if a match is found, set it to `true`.

After the loop is over, check `abbrvFound` to decide if you need to add `listTest1` object or not.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listTest1.Count; i++) {
    bool abbrvFound = false;
    for (int a = 0; a < listTest2.Count; a++) {
        if (listTest1[i].abbrv != listTest2[a].abbrv)
            continue;
        abbrvFound = true;
        if (listTest1[i].date == listTest2[a].date) {
            listTest3.Add(listTest2[a]);
        } else {
            listTest3.Add(new Test.Test2() { abbrv = listTest2[a].abbrv, date = listTest2[a].date, completed = true, abbrevName = listTest2[a].abbrevName });
            listTest3.Add(new Test.Test2() { abbrv = listTest1[i].abbrv, date = listTest1[i].date, completed = listTest1[i].completed, abbrevName = string.Empty });
        }
    }
    if (!abbrvFound) {
        listTest3.Add(new Test.Test2() { abbrv = listTest1[i].abbrv, date = listTest1[i].date, completed = listTest1[i].completed, abbrevName = string.Empty });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you help me with the code changes.

Comment: @LioProgramista Do you see the code added in the edit?